# Yii2 SearchModel как выбрать записи, которые не имеют записей в другой таблице?

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Суть вопроса - в одной таблице есть записи. Есть связь с другой таблицей 1:n. Как отфильтровать записи из первой таблицы, не имеющие связанных записей во второй? На SQL это легко сделать, но как это сделать, используя ActiveRecord в SearchModel Yii2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу сам:

```
 $query->join('LEFT OUTER JOIN', 'table2 t2', '`t2`.`table1_id` = `table1`.`id`');
 $query->andWhere(['t2.id' => NULL]);
```